# How to remove the fireplace hearth

Tags: flooring, floor, fireplace, hearth

I have removed a fire place surround. And removed the piece that sat on the floor in front of the fire.
**Before removal**
[image: fireplace before demolition]

But after removal there is some kind of cement that is on the floor in front and is level with the carpet (see below) so to install new carpet I will need to get rid of it. Is it safe and easy to do with a chisel and hammer?

[image: Concrete hearth left behind]

Comment: If that was originally a real fireplace you might find that hearth is solid down to the ground. Or at least a perimeter wall that is filled with earth and poured over. Smack it with a hammer if it sounds hollow go for it, if the hammer rebounds like it’s trying to hit you back it may be solid and hammer & chisel will take quite a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chisel and hammer worked perfectly. The stuff in front of the wall was just mortar, so once I got an edge on it it started to come away quite easily. Then once the top layer was all out, any tiny stubborn bits I sanded away with a sander.

Worth wearing a mask for this because of the mortar dust